# Parse LiveQuery in Cloud Code

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, livequery

I have an iOS and android application, deployed in a Parse Server. Now, I want to use the LiveQuery SDK, from a cloud function!

Here's my cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("subscribeQueryFunction", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Message");
    var subscription = query.subscribe();

    subscription.on("create", (object) => {
        response.success(object);
    });
});
```

And my Swift code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "subscribeQueryFunction", withParameters: nil) { (res: Any?, e: Error?) in
        print(res)
        print(e)
    }
}
```

The thing is, that the client doesn't get a response! Although, I checked the logs and the subscription seems to be established:

`2017-05-14T16:49:12.442Z - Ran cloud function subscribeQueryFunction for user D7FP3cts5p with:
  Input: {}
  Result: {"text":"hey","createdAt":"2017-05-14T16:49:12.412Z","updatedAt":"2017-05-14T16:49:12.412Z","objectId":"DXCiumOTal","__type":"Object","className":"Message"}
2017-05-14T16:49:11.101Z - Ran cloud function subscribeQueryFunction for user D7FP3cts5p with:
  Input: {}
  Result: {"text":"hey","createdAt":"2017-05-14T16:49:11.044Z","updatedAt":"2017-05-14T16:49:11.044Z","objectId":"qkXS6csCKJ","__type":"Object","className":"Message"}
2017-05-14T16:49:09.099Z - Ran cloud function subscribeQueryFunction for user D7FP3cts5p with:
  Input: {}
  Result: {"text":"hey","createdAt":"2017-05-14T16:49:09.080Z","updatedAt":"2017-05-14T16:49:09.080Z","objectId":"ydnrDHO9AP","__type":"Object","className":"Message"}
2017-05-14T16:47:45.183Z - Create new client: 0`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want do that ?

Comment: @JulienKode because I want a code to be written once, for iOS and Android and not have the developers code it separately

Comment: Oh I understand, but I don't think Live Query is made to use on the server side. This works with web sockets

Comment: You can have you logic on your server and this is a good idea

Comment: You want at each new object, send to your iOS and Android client ?

Comment: You want at each new object, send to your iOS and Android client ?

Comment: I want to create a messaging app, so you get the idea

Comment: Oh I understand, I answer your question and I have a good idea for you, I use the same, and It works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live Query is not made to use on the server side.
Live Query use web sockets, to interact in real time with your client.
But when you app is close the socket is close too ... So want you need is push notifications

If you want to make a real time messaging application with parse your need to:

- Implement Parse Live Query to get new messages with the web sockets when you app is open
- Use push notifications, so when you app is close, you get the new messages